# Negative look-ahead always returns true

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am using this regular expression

```
/(?!results)/i
```

As far as I understand, it will match any string that does not contain the word "result". However, when I try

```
/(?!results)/i.test('basketball results')
```

it returns `true`. How do I match strings that do not contain the word `results`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex matches every position that has no `results` after it. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kK3rG4/4).

To match an expression that does not contain `results`, you need to use `^(?!.*results.*$).*`. See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/kK3rG4/3).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) check here. It will return `-1` is a substring is not contained in the string and zero or greater otherwise:

```
"basketball results".indexOf('results') == -1
```